# How can I transfer a variable from Python Flask to JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, python, flask, get, fetch

I am developing a simple website with Python Flask and JavaScript for my machine learning project. It has a form which gets data from the user, then predict a target and send it back to the user. I set the action of form as "index", and When the form is submitted the page "index.html" should be loaded. I tried using POST method to get data from JavaScript and it works, but on the other hand, I cannot transfer the answer from Python to JavaScript.
My code for POST method is something like this:

```
@app.route('/',methods = ['POST', 'GET'])
def myFunction():
if request.method == "POST":
    myVariable = request.form["example"]
    answer = myModel.predition(myVariable)

    return redirect(url_for("index"))

else:
    return render_template("myWeb.html")
```

I tried using GET method in Flask and fetch in JS to transfer the answer but as my answer variable is in myFunction(), I cannot use GET outside of it. Furthermore, when I tried to show a simple string as answer it didn't work. My code was something like this:

```
@app.route('/index',methods = ['POST', 'GET'])
def answer():
if request.method == 'GET':
    message = {"prediction"}
    return jsonify(message)
```

and my JS was:

```
fetch('/index')
    .then(function (response) {
          return response.json();
  }).then(function (text) {
      console.log('GET response:');
      console.log(text); 
  });
```

I really don't know how should I fix this and show my answer on index.html successfully. I take Internal Server Error on index page.

Comment: completly unrelated, but using `function` for those fetch callbacks is really odd. arrow functions are much cleaner and more readable there, e.g. `.then(response => response.json())`

Answer (score 0):

`message = {"prediction"}` is a Set that contains your string. As usually sets are not JSON serializable. You have to use a list here `message = ["prediction"]` (or remove the brackets to return as simply string)

Btw: You're indentation looks broken... Maybe it's a copy&paste issue, but please check if your code is correct indented.